# RxJS: How does Pipe method make the operators work it takes as arguments internally?

Tags: rxjs

I've been looking into `pipe` method source code and I couldn't find any clue about triggering the operator it takes as arguments.
According to what I've seen in the source code, first, `pipe` method takes the `operations` which are `OperatorFunction` type, not just operators, as arguments. Then, it calls `pipeFromArray` function, passing the operations to it. In the `pipeFromArray` function, it iterates the `operations` with `reduce` method. Here is the tricky part: I looked into the `map` operator, for example, the operation(in this case, `mapOperation` function) that `pipe` takes as an argument, does nothing but returns an new Observable which gets to have the `MapOperator`. I want to know in which point in the source code, the operators or operations get triggered. `MapOperator` does have `call` method which I'm assuming is the trigger but I can't see any implementation that calls the `call` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pipe` ultimately only returns an observable after having chained the operators (as you already noticed). Observables in general only get »called« once you actually *subscribe* to them, thus your answer lies in `Observable.ts` itself; more specifically, in the [`subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L191) function:

```js
subscribe(observerOrNext?: PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void),
          error?: (error: any) => void,
          complete?: () => void): Subscription {

  const { operator } = this;
  const sink = toSubscriber(observerOrNext, error, complete);

  if (operator) {
    operator.call(sink, this.source);
  } else {
    sink.add(this.source ? this._subscribe(sink) : this._trySubscribe(sink));
  }

  return sink;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused because according to their comments in the source code, >pipe returns the Observable result of all of the operators having been called in the order they were passed in. So I thought the chained operators in `pipe` was called one by one before `subscribe` and the last observable which results from the last operator in the chaining waits for the `subscribe` function. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can see in the operator's `call` implementation that they in turn call `subscribe` on the source observable, which creates the subscription chain. `pipe` chains them in the sense that it combines them, but operators are only executed once subscribed.

Comment: As you explained, the `subscribe` method calls the operator's call method and it keeps going upward through `source` connection and at the end of the flow, there will be like [MapSubscriber, FilterSubscriber, etc] in the subscription array, if it was like source$.pipe(map(), filter()).subscribe()), if I get it correct. One last question though: Where can I see the implementation that calls the `_next` method in each subscriber? In the `subscribe` method, it simply adds the subscription but I can't see how the `_next` method is trigged in chain.

Comment: @DongBinKim `_next`, which is the internal method wrapped by the public `next`, gets the subscriber as the destination argument and forwards notifications that way.

Comment: Yeah I get that but what I'm asking is where exactly in code calls the `next` method? I want to know how/what/where in code actually calls the method that triggers the each operator's logic in chain

Comment: Look at the Subscriber class itself (from which the subscriber classes of operators extend). They call `next` on the `destination`.